# Displaying an indoor building map with route tracing draw path to rooms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, svg

I need to display a map of multi-level building on a website. This website will only be displayed on a PC in the foyer of this building.

I need to allow people to do a room search and then draw directions to the room on the map. I also need people to zoom and drag the map too.

I have watched the Google "Map your business, inside and out" video and can see a lot of that could be useful, but there is nothing there to be able to show directions from one room to another.

So before I spend a lot of time writing my own code using jQuery, I was wondering if anyone else has done something similar, or if anyone can suggest some good starting points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found really nice plugin that meets my requirements.

https://github.com/ucdavis/wayfinding